# why my unit test failing after adding a parameter?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Here is my code when working fine

```
verify(loginService).getUser(eq(loginName));
```

here it is failing..

```
@Test
public void test_getUserFlow4() {
    ...
    LoginModel loginModelReturned = loginService.getUser(loginName, null);
    assertGeneralConditions(loginModelReturned);
    ...
}

private void assertGeneralConditions(LoginModel loginModelReturned){
    verify(loginService).getUser(eq(loginName), null);  //test failed here other lines not executed
    ....
    ....
}
```

here is the getUser method

```
public LoginModel getUser(String loginName, String userAgent) {
    // userAgent is not being used anywhere
    ....
    return model;
}
```

Exact Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

Comment: My guess is that you're using Mockito. Please give more details, including the error message in the test failure.

Comment: In your first snippet you are invoking `getUser` with a single parameter. Where is that?

Comment: You're still not providing valuable details. What are your expectations? What are the actual results?

Comment: @JonSkeet more details added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using argument matches, you need to use them for *all* arguments. So to fix your test, you can just use:

```
verify(loginService).getUser(eq(loginName), Matchers.<String>eq(null));
```

Or:

```
verify(loginService).getUser(eq(loginName), (String) isNull());
```

Or personally, I'd clarify this by simply having a `userAgent` variable with a value of `null`:

```
String userAgent = null;
verify(loginService).getUser(eq(loginName), eq(userAgent));
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Given that `Mockito` extends `Matchers`, what's the benefit of `Mockito` over `Matchers`, for invoking a static method?

Comment: No, never mind. I thought you were referring to something else.

Comment: Thanks GOD! we have Jon Skeet, who can always understand the poorly described questions!